# Can AirAsia reprint boarding passes long after the flight was taken?

Tags: tickets, paperwork, philippines, airasia

I need the boarding pass for scholarship reasons, but the boarding pass I got from the self check in machine already faded (thermal paper). Is it possible for AirAsia (Philippines) to reprint the boarding pass?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried asking AirAsia?

Comment: Very unlikely. Boarding passes are only issued for active reservations that are open for check in.  Contact whoever is asking for the boarding pass and ask what else they accept: booking confirmation, invoice, itinerary, etc. These days paper boarding passes are an unreasonable expectation: in many cases, they are electronic and they disappear from your phone after the flight. Some airline actually charge extra for printing one at the airport. There has to be a alternative.

Comment: Back then did you get a PDF boarding pass by email or anything like that? Also what is the reason they need the boarding pass? Would the ticket receipt not be enough? Or passport stamp, depending on the reason they need it…